# Site manager disapeared following EE 3.0 release?

Tags: multi-site-manager

sorry if this is a dumb question, but what happened to the Site Manager for EE 2.*? I need it for a project and its gone from the Store pages and the links are dead.

Anyone know anything?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All of their EE 2 documentation also became dead links. I honestly think they dropped the ball on this.

Comment: You can download the EE 2 docs from EllisLab (there is a link in the upper right corner of the [user guide](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/)). There is also http://ee2docs.com/. Seems too soon for them to be removing it from the store, but I think you'll have to contact EllisLab to get hold of MSM for EE2.

Comment: They did the same thing from EE1 to EE2, where there was a period of about a month or so where you couldn't get at certain parts of the documentation or websites. Let's hope the EE3 code is better tested than their website.